# Merge values of an array into a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have an array that I would like to put into a single cell, with commas to make a list.  I'm starting with an array of varying length in column BY:

Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
Purple
Brown
White
Black
Orange

and I want to have all of these put into a cell so it reads, "Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Purple, Brown, White, Black, Orange"

The list is dynamic, so sometimes it will be just 1 color and other times it may have 50 colors.

I was trying things like,

```
=concatenate(arrayformula('1'!BY1:BY))
```

but that returns RedBlueGreenYellowPurpleBrownWhiteBlackOrange

Any ideas for me?  Thank you in advance!
NJD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want is [`join`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en), as in

```
=join(", ", BY1:BY)
```

or, since you probably want to exclude empty cells at the bottom of that column,

```
=join(", ", filter(BY1:BY, len(BY1:BY)))
```

where [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) keeps only nonempty cells.